# How do I get presents from elemental pillars?

Tags: skylanders

I am trying to finish the objective of getting three presents from an elemental pillar. Sometimes I get coins, but it still says 0/3 for the presents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be the first person to click on the present as soon as you've collapsed the pillar.  Which probably isn't going to happen if there's anyone else there.  Faster fingers might help, click like mad on it while the last block is being destroyed.
Your best bet might be to wander around until you find a pillar that nobody else has seen yet and try to knock it down before anyone else comes over to open your present for you.  Everybody wants to be helpful!